# Epimorphism that is not surjective in the category of Torsion Free Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups

In reading about cokernels (relating to a homework question I have) I came across the following:

https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jg352/pdf/CTSheet4-2013.pdf

I specifically wondered about question 5a. Therein the author claims that in the category of torsion-free Abelian groups that not every epimorphism is surjective.

This would clearly mean that the cokernel of a epimorphism that is not surjective would need to be torsion (which relates to the homework question I am working on).

However, I have yet to find an epimorphism in the category of torsion-free abelian groups that is *not* surjective.

Is the author's claim true? If so, what types of maps should I look at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: the example given by Slade is correct, but there are more basic examples, like $(2\cdot) : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$

The inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is the usual counterexample of a ring epimorphism that isn't surjective

Let $f : A \to B$. We say $f$ is epi if and only if for all $g,h:B \to C$

$g \circ f = h \circ f$ implies $g = h$

If your category is enriched in abelian groups (like the category of torsion-free abelian groups), then this is equivalent to the requirement that for all $g : B \to C$

$g \circ f = 0$ implies $g = 0$

Now let $f : A \to B$ a map between torsion-free abelian groups such that the cokernel is non-zero torsion.

Suppose further that $g : B \to C$, where $C$ is torsion-free such that $g \circ f = 0$

Denote by $\mathrm{cok} f : B \to B/\mathrm{im} f$ the quotient map.

By the universal property there is a unique map $g' : B/\mathrm{im} f \to C$ such $g = g' \circ \mathrm{cok} f$.

Now $g'$ is a map from a torsion group to a torsion-free group, so it must be $0$. Hence $g = 0 \circ \mathrm{cok} f = 0$.

(In a more abstract language, we're using that taking torsion is functorial)

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: ... in the category of torsion-free abelian groups.